# Controlling direction of normal vector, matlab

Tags: matlab, plane

I have few  hundred points. Connecting them gives me a few hundred planes. I need to control the direction of the normal vector, such that I always look at this plane from outside of building.

Here are some points.

```
XYZ=[1,26.7801084079290,10.9279762852855,5.90125567150161;
1,26.7801084079290,10.6329762852855,5.90125567150161;
1,26.7801084079290,10.6329762852855,7.78125567150161;
1,26.7801084079290,10.9279762852855,7.78125567150161;
1,26.7801084079290,10.9279762852855,5.90125567150161;
2,31.2001083983270,10.9279762852855,5.89675567150161;
2,31.2001083983270,10.6329762852855,5.89675567150161;
2,31.2001083983270,10.6329762852855,7.77675567150161;
2,31.2001083983270,10.9279762852855,7.77675567150161;
2,31.2001083983270,10.9279762852855,5.89675567150161;
2,31.2001083983270,10.9279762852855,5.89675567150161;]
```

fitting a plane with least squares method gives me folloing parameters

```
1   1 0 0 26.78  % [plane number, n, d]
2   1 0 0 31.2
```

plotting these points

[image]

As  i'm looking from outside to inside of building,plane number 2 is ok. But How can I change plane 1 direction. It shows me direction of normal inside the building.It should be oppsite direction.

Note: I have hundreds of planes, so I need some systemtic way to get these plane normals in right direction.

%-----------------------Edited------------------------------------------------------%

% For clockwise and anticlock 
% I 'm getting same result

```
XYZ=[1,26.7801084079290,10.9279762852855,7.78125567150161;
    1,26.7801084079290,10.6329762852855,7.78125567150161;
    1,26.7801084079290,10.6329762852855,5.90125567150161;
    1,26.7801084079290,10.9279762852855,5.90125567150161;        
    2,26.7801084079290,10.6329762852855,5.90125567150161;
    2,26.7801084079290,10.6329762852855,7.78125567150161;
    2,26.7801084079290,10.9279762852855,7.78125567150161;
    2,26.7801084079290,10.9279762852855,5.90125567150161; ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can determine if a point is behind of a plane with the D term of the general equation

```
  N.P0 + D0 = 0 => D0 = - N.P0 (dot product)
```

where P0 is a point inside the plane and N is the normal

if you make the calculations with other point (P1) to get (D1), if D1>D0 means that P1 is behind P0.

P1 is can be easily calcultated if the building is convex.

Other approach is ensuring that the points that generate the planes, are in clockwise order (or counterclockwise)